# Detecting and Printing Streaks

Tags: python

I wrote up a bit of code to detect streaks in data and am just wondering why it's not working.

I've got a sequence of -1s, 0s and 1s. I'd like to report on where the nonzero values are. But they tend to come in streaks; so rather than just reporting individual locations, I'd like to report streaks. Here is a simple example:

```
sequence=[-1,-1,0,0,1,1]

print('Negative Influences:')
streaking=False
streak=[]
for j in range(len(sequence)):
    if streaking==False and sequence[j]==-1:
        streaking==True
        streak.append(j)
    elif streaking==True and sequence[j]==-1:
        streak.append(j)
    elif streaking==True and sequence[j]!=-1:
        streaking==False
        print(streak)
        streak=[]

print('Positive Influences:')
streaking=False
streak=[]
for j in range(len(sequence)):
    if streaking==False and sequence[j]==1:
        streaking==True
        streak.append(j)
    elif streaking==True and sequence[j]==1:
        streak.append(j)
    elif streaking==True and sequence[j]!=1:
        streaking==False
        print(streak)
        streak=[]
```

I'd expect the following output:

```
Negative Influences: [0,1]
Positive Influences: [4,5]
```

Unfortunately, I get blanks:

```
Negative Influences:
Positive Influences:
```

To debug, I tried adding a print(streaking) command at the end of each iteration. It revealed that streaking is always False. Why is that? streaking is supposed to become True when it hits the first -1 (or 1, respectively).

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by streaks. Basically you need indices of negative and positive numbers, right?

Comment: A run of consecutive -1s, or 1s.

Comment: What should this output?: `[-1,0,-1,0,1,1]`

Comment: Yes, the indices of negative and positive numbers, but reported in streaks. So if I get 100 straight -1s, I'd like to report that as a single block rather than 100 individual entries.

Comment: For your example

Negative Influences:
[0]
[2]

Positive Influences:
[4,5]

Comment: Admittedly my code would still print each individual index of negative and positive numbers; but I could easily modify it to print only the first and last index of a streak. Want to get this version working first though.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error: I used == instead of = when setting streaking to True at the start of a streak.

Sorry for the bother

Answer (score 0):

By mistake, you have wrote == for change the streaking value from False to True and True to False while you should write = instead of == for assign or change value of variable

**WRONG**

```
streaking==True
```

**Right**

```
streaking=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are aware what's wrong with your code, I suggest another straight-forward approach that does this job in one iteration:

```
from itertools import groupby

sequence = [-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1,1]

pos, neg = [], []
cnt = 0

for k, g in groupby(sequence):
    g = list(g)
    if k == -1 and len(g) == 1:
        neg.append(cnt)
    elif k == -1 and len(g) > 1:
        neg.append([cnt, cnt + len(g) - 1])
    elif k == 1 and len(g) == 1:
        pos.append(cnt)
    elif k == 1 and len(g) > 1:
        pos.append([cnt, cnt + len(g) - 1])
    cnt += len(g)

print(neg)  # [0, [2, 9]]
print(pos)  # [[12, 15]]
```